# Number of translation units vs number of cpp files

Tags: c++, translation-unit

We have 2 cases (scenarios). In each case, we have 2 files : `main.cpp` and `file.cpp`

**Case 1**

- main.cpp :

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "file.cpp"  // this line is what matters

int main () {...}
```

I compile and run by doing:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main && ./main
```

**Case 2**

- main.cpp :

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void filefunc(int); // function declaration from file.cpp

int main () {...}
```

I compile and run by doing:

```
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -c file.cpp
g++ main.o file.o -o main && ./main
```

How many `translation units` do we have in each case ? is it :

- one for the first
- two for the second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you pass a file of source code to `g++`, that is a translation unit. By definition.

The file extension is practically irrelevant, but conventionally we reserve ".cpp" for things that we pass to the compiler, not things we `#include`.

In the first case, your ill-advised inclusion of a `.cpp` file results in a *single* translation unit that would confuse your fellow programmers and cause rejection at code review.

In the second case, you have two translation units.

This time, the end result — the executable — is the same though.

Comment: And note that on that translation unit being what you pass to the compiler bit, it is actually possible to have more TUs than source files by passing particular files to the compiler more than once (presumably with different preprocessor symbols defined)

Comment: @SoronelHaetir example ?

Comment: @MohamedBenkedadra https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc70ad77abe13fbf